# WSO2 Dev Studio 3.7.0 fails when attempting to use XPath

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

We are attempting to move all of our proxy service and mediation development to Developer Studio, which is the approved and supported method. We have installed Developer’s Studio as per the instructions in the installation guide on several workstations.  We have succeeded in deploying some simply proxy services to our shared ESB in our integration environment. As long we stick to simple mediators which do not use Xpath things seem to work fine.

Our next step was to attempt to work through the tutorial presented here: 
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/06/develop-and-deploy-esb-artifacts-using-wso2-developer-studio/

However, when we attempt to use the properties mediator as described in the tutorial, we are unable to save the proxy service. The error message is XPathFactory#newInstance failed to create an XPath for the default object model http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom. The end of the error message is "Illegal Configuration-File Syntax".

Version information: WSO2 Dev Studio 3.7.0. JDK 1.7.0_69.

I can't post the stack trace in full because it goes over the 2 link limit, but the first entry is equivalent to the error message.

The expression generating the error is  //heal:getHealthCareCenterInfo/heal:longitude/text()